# Highcharts pre-processing live data example isn't working

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I am trying to use the example of Highcharts where you can live view the data. But when I run the website it immediately wants to download the websitepage (charts2.php). When I delete the JSON header in the PHP code, it doesn't want to download anything but then again the highchart doesn't return anything. Can somebody help me please. Still new to this though..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">

  <script>
    var chart; // global

    /**
     * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout to request again
     */
    function requestData() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'live-server-data.php', 
        success: function(point) {
          var series = chart.series[0],
            shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20

          // add the point
          chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);

          // call it again after one second
          setTimeout(requestData, 1000);  
        },
        cache: false
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
          events: {
            load: requestData
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          tickPixelInterval: 150,
          maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
          minPadding: 0.2,
          maxPadding: 0.2,
          title: {
            text: 'Value',
            margin: 80
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Random data',
          data: []
        }]
      });   
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

      <?php

// Set the JSON header
header("Content-type: text/json");

// The x value is the current JavaScript time, which is the Unix time multiplied 
// by 1000.
$x = time() * 1000;
// The y value is a random number
$y = rand(0, 100);

// Create a PHP array and echo it as JSON
$ret = array($x, $y);
echo json_encode($ret);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The prompt to download the *.php page leads me to believe you do not have PHP set up correctly on your server.

Comment: What your php returns, live-server-data.php and why you use eval() instaed of return data (in php) by json_encode() ?